# Cant get my fixed to top navigation next to each other

Tags: html, css, navigation, block, inline

I have read almost 50 articles about how to get divs or anything next to each other with html and css, but i simply can't find the mistake I am making.

My HTML looks like this:

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#index">aaaaaa</img></a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#over">bbbbbb</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#muziek">cccccc</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#gigs">dddddd</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#contact">eeeeee</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
nav {
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    }

li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 10%;   
    }
```

Notice that my navigation bar, and the links inside it are both foxed to top.
Right now all the links are stacked on top of each other on the place where i want the first link.
Next I want the links to get next to each other, instead of on top of each other.
Any help would be great :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to remove `position: fixed` from `a` elements. Also remove `float: left` from `li` elements(`display: inline-block` is enough):

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 58px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  top: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#index">aaaaaa</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#over">bbbbbb</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#muziek">cccccc</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#gigs">dddddd</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#contact">eeeeee</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This worked! I knew the double fixed position was odd haha.Thanks!

Comment: @Frank If the answer works, click the checkmark below the votes count of answer (users call this action *accept answer* or *mark answer as correct*).

Answer (score 1):

Once adding `position:fixed` to the header itself, you don't need to add it anywhere anymore. Adding  `position:fixed` makes all the positions of header's childs relative to the header. As header is fixed, you don't need to fix each child one more time because `position:fixed` fixes the element relatively to the body. Thats why you get all the links layered one on another.